# How to fix mysql2date() for 5.3.2 version?

Tags: date-time

When I upgrade Wordpress into 5.3.2 version, a date on a PDF invoice generated by a plugin disapeared.
The function `mysql2date()` which makes the date is a wp function and used in the plugin like this :

```
$dateFacture = mysql2date('j F Y',time() );
```

**Output**

```
WP < 5.3.2 => returns the current date
WP = 5.3.2 => returns NULL
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the function `time()` as paramater so I had to change the code line by :

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$dateFacture = mysql2date('j F Y', $today );
```